News overview not starting as opened
We have a section in a webpage coded in php but it is not starting as active then users load the page. they first have to click news or blogs to see anything. i want to have news as open
<?php if( get_row_layout() == 'newsblog_section' ): ?>
<div class="over_grip_wrapper wp_left">
  <div class="container news_list_wrapper">
    <div class="main_menu wp_left">
      <ul>
<?php $categories = get_categories();
          $list=1;
foreach($categories as $category) { ?>    
      <li><a class="<?php if($list==1) { echo "active"; } ?>" data-id="<?php echo "list".$list; ?>" href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id) ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a></li>
            <?php $list++; } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container news_list_content_wrapper">
    <?php $categories = get_categories();
        $list=1;
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $catid = $category->term_id; ?>
    <div id="<?php echo "list".$list; ?>" class="news_blog_cover_wrapper wp_left">  
    <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'post','tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $catid
        ))); 
 query_posts($args);
 $counter=1; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
    <div class="over_grip_content_wrapper wp_left">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="wp_left cover_news_image">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid w-100' )); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="over_grip_box wp_left">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_field('short_description'); ?><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
        <?php $counter++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php $list++; } wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

Unfortunately, the entirety of the file containing all CSS code is too large to share. However, I can provide excerpts or specific sections upon request.
.news_blog_cover_wrapper .over_grip_content_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.news_blog_cover_wrapper .over_grip_content_wrapper:last-child
{
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

.news_blog_cover_wrapper
{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    height::0px;
}
.news_blog_cover_wrapper
{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    height:0px;
}
.news_blog_cover_wrapper.active
{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    height:auto;
}

.news_blog_cover_wrapper.over_grip_content_wrapper
{
display:none;
}
.news_blog_cover_wrapper.over_grip_content_wrapper.active
{
display:block;
}

It's supposed to start open.

Could you post your CSS code as well? You might need to apply the CSS property display: block; to your news_blog_cover_wrapper class.

I have added it to the post :)
